# Is there any difference between contact forms across sites?

Tags: support, contact

Sometimes when a user comes into chat with a problem, or asks about it on meta, the answer involves contacting the SE staff, and if I'm the one that answers I'll provide a link to the contact form.

To that end, do all entries on the /contact forms go to the same place regardless of the site (e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact vs. https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact)?

Does it make a difference which one is used? I.e. if a user has a problem on, say, Ask Ubuntu, does it cause problems if they fill out the form on, say, UX?

I usually link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact, but just wondering if there's a difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you contact the Stack Exchange team, all messages currently go to the same place. However, using the contact form *on the site you need help with* is a good idea because...

- **When messages come in, the name of the site you're reaching out from is visible to us. Some minimal profile info is also available.**
  This information goes a long way in helping us get to the root of the problem quickly.
- **Some procedures for correcting account issues (e.g. merges) can be self-serviced, some of the time, but you'll need to reach out via the right site to do it.**

Chances are, if you use a contact form on a different site, we're going to have to ask you for clarification. Reaching out from the right site will save you and us a few extra steps, so it's a good habit to get into. As they say, help us help you.

Comment: Also, now that we have [Collectives on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives), there is a "Collectives" option in the dropdown [only on SO's Contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). (I'm not sure if there are any other options that only appear on certain sites.)